# Dealing with input to recurrent net with changing dimensions

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

I have a problem in which the dimensions of the input are increasing in row and column at each timestep. What method for preprocessing could be done or are there any architectures used for solving such a case?